# Team Foundation Server set Workspace Local Path to Source directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I am having a lot of issues configuring TFS to work correctly.  One other web developer and I both work on a website (w/ roughly 80,000 pages).  We have our development code on a server that we both share.  Currently when either of us makes changes, we simply SFTP from that share to the live site.

We would like to configure TFS so that both of our local paths in our workspaces map to that shared server (same location) so that we can easily sftp everything after save.

In other words when I save a file even though I am using TFS, I want that saved version to be the version on our development server.

Can I do this the way that I suggested above or is there a better method?

Do I need to set each of our local paths separately and then do a get on the development box every single time I want the file to update?  Can I force our development box to get the latest TFS version every time the file is checked in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend that both of you work in the same set of files at the same time. You will end up stepping on each other, and getting into weird conditions with different versions of files (i.e., you do a get and he does a get at the same time - worst case is getting different versions). You may end up checking in each other's changes at the wrong time.

Glauco's suggestion is good. Another would be to use the build feature of TFS. You can do everything in msbuild if you like, and there's an FTP task at http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/. You could also modify the workflow, though the learning curve is steeper if you've never done it. You can find file copying activity in http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/.

Another option would be to have a workspace on the development box where you have a scheduled task in Windows that runs get on it every so often.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom Check-In policy that automatically attempts to copy my local file to the server each time a file is checked in.  This has worked well.  Here is another related question that I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571063/tfs-custom-check-in-policy-is-not-in-the-add-box

Answer (score 1):

I really do recommend you to use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

With Jenkins and the [Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) you could watch a TFS repository and get the latests version of it every time someone do a check in. You could also do other tasks, like run your automated tests, generate sonar reports and so on.

For me, Jenkins is a way better to do what you want.

Comment: We are pretty restricted as to the software that we can install.  I will take a look at Jenkins though.

Answer (score 0):

Select the source from Team Explorer, then in Visual Studio , Go the File, Then Workspaces and the select your desired workspace, click edit and then modify the working folders in the pop up window. Better to delete the existing and then map to your needs