# TFS Custom Check-In Policy is not in the Add box

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have followed the steps on this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx to create a TFS Custom Check-In Policy.  I have updated the registry as it suggests except to Visual Studio 11.0 instead of 8.0

In Visual Studio 2012 -> Team Explorer -> Settings -> Source Control ->Check-In Policy Tab I click on Add.  I see 4 policies, but mine is not listed.

I have VS 2012 installed on my computer.  I created the policy dll with VS2012 and referenced the 11.0 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client assembly.

Please note TFS 2010 is installed on the source control server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your OS is 64-bit, you must add the checkin policy under the **Wow6432Node** instead of the path stated on MSDN:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies
```

**UPDATE**

An alternative registry path, at least used when installing policies through an extension (.vsix) is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have a 32 bit system though.

Comment: Too bad :/. That was the solution for us a while ago. We use TFS 2010 with VS 2012 as well. We have selected to install our policies through a .vsix extension, and it seems the registry path differs: see update.

Comment: Torbjorn, thanks that did the trick!  I used the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry path as you suggested and it is now visible in the Add dialog box.  I manually added this key (without using the VSIX file).

Comment: The second path only worked for me, on 64-bit OS without using VSIX.

Comment: Neither of the above works for me in TFS 2015 (using 14.0/14.0_Config). Does anyone know if the registry locations changed?

Comment: Actually, I realized I was still referencing the 10.0 version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll. The second registry key is the one that now works for me too.