# Error Loading Custom Check-In Policy Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2015, checkin-policy

A few years ago, I asked this question: [TFS Custom Check-In Policy is not in the Add box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571063/tfs-custom-check-in-policy-is-not-in-the-add-box) and was able to get my custom check-in policy to work in Visual Studio 2012.  I have finally upgraded to VS2015RC and am trying to use the same check-in policy.  I have tried to add a reference at the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies
```

but have had no luck.  I also opened my check-in policy project in VS2015 and rebuilt it (attempting to target various different frameworks: 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6) all with no luck.

I also changed my references of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.versionControl.Client to version 14.0.0.0

Does anyone know why I can't get this policy to show up in the Add Check-In Policy dialog?

Answer (score 1):

All that it needed was a night of rest.

This morning I woke up to the Check-In policy working as expected.  My computer had restarted overnight which I assume corrected the issue.

I do want to note that while working on this issue yesterday, I tried closing Visual Studio 2015 every time that I changed the registry, etc, but that didn't seem to help.  I also logged off/on once and that didn't fix it.

So final answer: computer restart seemed to fix the issue.  Also, for future reference, my custom check-in policy is targeting .Net Framework 4.5.1